# Как использовать в тексте переменные, используя return в goLang?

Tags: golang

```
 name := "Георгий"
 return "Привет, %v", name
```

Однако произойдет ошибка, например в fmt.Printf() все будет ок

Comment: Собрать в одну строку и вернуть эту строку

Answer (score 3):

Можно воспользоваться функцией [fmt.Sprintf](https://pkg.go.dev/fmt#Sprintln):

```
name := "Георгий"
return fmt.Sprintf("Привет, %v", name)
```

синтаксис подобен Printf, только она не печатает, а отдает в качестве строки.